# Kibana/Elastic Query on multiple terms in same array element

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

In my Elasticsearch Index I have documents which contain an array of uniform elements, like this:

Document 1:

```
"listOfElements": {
    "entries": [{
            "key1": "value1",
            "int1": 4,
            "key2": "value2"
        }, {
            "key1": "value1",
            "int1": 7,
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Document 2:

```
"listOfElements": {
    "entries": [{
            "key1": "value1",
            "int1": 5,
            "key2": "value2"
        }, {
            "key1": "value1",
            "int1": 7,
            "key2": "value2"
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I want to create a query that returns all documents which have, e.g. key1:value1 AND int1:4 in the same entry element.

However, if I only query for "key1:value1 AND int1:4" I obviously get all documents that have key1:value1 and all that have int1:4 so I would get both documents from the above example.

Is there any way to query for multiple fields that have to be in the same array element?

Comment: Look into https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html . You will need to have nested type in your mapping as well.

Comment: You need to update the mapping for listOfElements.entries as nested ( https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/nested.html) instead of object (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/object.html)

Comment: Thanks slawek and Ram. I think this is exactly what I need to do. Could one of you post this as an answer so I can accept it?